# Can I use a baseUrl like this in protractor?

Tags: angular, testing, protractor

I'm trying to test a SPA where the baseUrl is https://clarity.design/news, but when I'm trying to navigate to a specific page, for example, 1.3.1, the URL will be https://clarity.design/1.3.1 which can't be found. It seems like it overwrites the news part from the URL.
This is my config:

```
exports.config = {
    baseUrl: 'https://clarity.design/news',
    seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
    specs: ['first-spec.js']
}
```

And the spec is

```
describe('Test', () => {
    beforeAll(async () => {
        await browser.get("/1.3.1");
    })
    it('should return home page title correctly', async () => {
        await browser.sleep(5000);
        expect(await browser.getTitle()).toContain('Page Not Found');
    });
});
```

So, is it possible to use a baseUrl like the one in config?

P.S. The test is modified so it can be regarded as passed.

Answer (score 0):

Use `browser.baseUrl`

`let myUrl = browser.baseUrl + "/1.3.1"
browser.get(myUrl)`

I guess you can do it in a more sophisticated way but I hope you got the idea

Comment: There is no browser.params.baseUrl in protractor browser, but there is browser.baseUrl which I'm going to use. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: @specialdoom Thanks (copy-paste from my code). I have edited the answer

Answer (score 0):

Many ways to solve it, but if I were you I would go this route

```
exports.config = {
    baseUrl: 'https://clarity.design/news',
    seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
    specs: ['first-spec.js']
}
```

and then explicitly say where you want to go

```
await browser.get("/news");
// or
await browser.get("/1.3.1");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below one

```
await browser.get(browser.baseUrl); //This will get your base URL
```

Hope it helps you